# Is this a Flood Fill program 8-way?

Tags: java, algorithm, flood-fill

Hey this works correctly, but after comparing it to the 4-way i can't find any differences...
If i were to hand this in would it be considered a correct method of implementing an 8-way flood algorithm?
A yes/no answer will suffice, but i figured I'd ask the experts before continuing

```
private void flood8(int col, int row, Color startColour) {

    if (startColour.equals(getPixel(col, row))) {
        setPixel(col, row);

        // this bit makes the animation work by
        // drawing intermediate results, and slowing the updates down
        synchronized (this) {
            draw();
       }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        // now we call the routine recursively for each neighbour
        // the "guard" surrounding each call ensures that we do
        // not try to keep going past the edge of the raster
        if (col + 1 < COLS) {
            flood4(col + 1, row, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position1 " + col + ", " + row );
        }
        if (col - 1 >= 0) {
            flood4(col - 1, row, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position2 " + col + ", " + row );
        }
        if (row + 1 < ROWS) {
            flood4(col, row + 1, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position3 " + col + ", " + row );
        }
        if (row - 1 <= 0) {
            flood4(col, row - 1, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position4 " + col + ", " + row );
        }
        if (col + 1 < COLS && row + 1 < ROWS) {
            flood4(col + 1, row, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position1 " + col + ", " + row );
        }
        if (col + 1 < COLS && row - 1 >= 0) {
            flood4(col - 1, row, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position2 " + col + ", " + row );
        }
        if (row - 1 >= 0 && row + 1 < ROWS) {
            flood4(col, row + 1, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position3 " + col + ", " + row );
        }
        if (row - 1 >= 0 && row - 1 >= 0) {
            flood4(col, row - 1, startColour);
            System.out.println("Position4 " + col + ", " + row );            
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: You call a `flood4` method a few times in this algorithm. Where is the definition of that method?

Comment: seems that you where calling flood4 inside your flood8, that is why you have not seen any difference.

Comment: You should do bounds checking at the top of the function instead of before each call.  That way it's in one place instead of 8.

Comment: You do bound checks for diagonal neighbours, but the (presumably) recursive call only changes one coordinate.

Comment: replace flood4 in your code with flood8 and it should work fine ..

Answer (score 0):

*Turning several comments into an answer, to get this out of the “unanswered” queue. Community wiki, so feel free to add.*

> would it be considered a correct method of implementing an 8-way flood algorithm?

Probably not, due to the following reasons:

- You call `flood4`, while a proper recursion should call `flood8` again.
- You do bound checks for diagonal neighbours, but the (presumably) recursive call only changes one coordinate.